# Porque no reconoce el modulo (python3.7.3.)

Tags: python

Tengo instalado el modulo Flask, pero al tratar de importarlo en el código, me aparece:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask' from '**main**'

la linea es la siguiente (no me deja pasar de alli):

```
from Flask import Flask
```

Comment: Por favor corre `pip list` y nos muestras qué módulos tienes instalados. Tampoco sabemos cómo estás intentando correr tu código

Comment: al ejecutar pip list aparecen: click - flask - flask.mysqldb  - pip ..... Estoy intentado correr el codigo desde sublime text 3

Comment: luego al tratar de ejtutarlo en sublime me da error de no reconoce el modulo y al tratar desde la consola con (python code.py) sucede lo mismo

Comment: Es un simple typo, el nombre del módulo es flask no Flask, debe ser from flask import Flask

Comment: @FJSevilla tal cual. hay que importarlo tal cual sale en la lista de módulos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos te sugiero lo siguiente

- Asegurarte que tu archivo py no lleve por nombre "**flask.py**" al igual
  que "**flask.pyc**" dado que esto ocasiona conflictos renombra a cualquier otro nombre.
- Instala la versión adecuada para python3.

  sudo apt-get install python3-flask

ó

```
sudo pip3 install flask
```

Error de sintaxis:

Actualmente tienes:

```
from Flask import Flask
```

cuando debe ser:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

Espero te sirva..!!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, mi archivo se llama code.py y no entiendo mucho de instalar una version adecuada para mi sistema operativo, me podrias explicar un poco eso?, estoy usando windows 7

Comment: Lo siento quize decir la version adecuada para Python3 en este caso...

Comment: probe instalarlo con pip y con pip3 (me sucede lo mismo en ambos casos)

Comment: @Arturo revisa mi respuesta la actulize..!!

Comment: perfecto, gracias por tu alluda tienes positivo, saludos

Comment: Gracias , es la correcta, tienes positivo saludos